# 言われたこと自体は気にしてないけど meaning

Tags: translation

Does it translate to " he doesn't mind being called that" ? Edit: 言われた means to be said, 自体 means itself and the context is about a person that gets called by a certain  nick name so I'm not sure if i should understand it as "he doesnt care being told/called that "or " he doesn't care about the nick name on itself "

Comment: We're not providing translations or proofreading so I voted to close your question. However, if you explain why you think `言われたこと自体は気にしてないけど` translates to `he doesn't mind being called that` or point out what is bothering you in the sentence then I will retract my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Under "normal" circumstances, native speakers would ***not*** use 「言{い}われたこと」 to refer to being addressed with a nickname.  We would use 「（そう）**呼{よ}ばれた**こと」.

If, however, someone addressed you with a completely new nickname that no one has ever addressed you with, you ***might*** use 「言われたこと」, then.

Most naturally, though, I would still say that upon hearing/reading 「言われたこと自体は気にしてない」, we would think that ***someone told you something*** (instead of just addressing you with a nickname) but that you are not bothered by it.

In short, you would ***not*** even talk about being bothered or not being bothered for being called by your nickname that "everyone" calls you by all the time, would you?

Thus, without further context or a more detailed background story, this is all I can say.